# Why doesn't the GeSHi filter work?

Tags: 8

I've installed GeSHi filter for Drupal 8. I've set it up so that the content type Full HTML has GeSHi filtering enabled.
I tried this on a basic page.

```
<code ="python">
def function_name(arg):
    pass
</code>
<python>
def function_name(arg):
    pass
</python>
```

For some reason, this is not being changed when I preview the page.

I do have the Libraries API installed, and it is detecting the GeSHi library.

Comment: Are there any errors or anything that you can report? PHP, Apache, JS console errors, anything?

Comment: If it is a bug in the module, then you should ask and report it on drupal.org's issue queue.